# Slide div down to middle of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**here is jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/arJEx/

Here's what I got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Waiting</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <style>
* { margin:0;padding:0; }
    #wait {

background:#ABC7D9;
border-top:4px solid #597F99;
border-bottom:4px solid #597F99;
padding:50px;
text-align:center;
font:23pt Georgia;
color:#1C5378;
display:none;
overflow: hidden;

    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$(".act").live("click",function() {
     $("#wait").slideDown("slow");
    });
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<button class="act">Activate effect</button>

<div id="wait">Please wait...</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I want it so the blue div when I press that button slides down to the middle of the page... but I juts can't seem to find out how to do it. Please help?

edit: ok, it doesn't HAVE to be middle of screen but near the top of part. like.. anywhere near middle to top of page.

Comment: That would be better if you create your question in jsFiddler and include the link in your question, this ways it would be very much easier to people to follow your question.

Comment: i will check out jsFiddler now... than kyou

Comment: Got it. http://jsfiddle.net/arJEx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is just fine with Your JS. You need to change CSS. First of all div's container must fill all window:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Than change div's css. First approach (not sure about IE):

```
#wait {
   /* remove padding and append those */
   position: absolute;
   top: 5%; /* change it */
   bottom: 50%;
   width: 100%
}
```

Second one:

```
#wait {
   /* remove padding and append those */
   height: 50%;
}
```

There is one problem You will need to solve. You will need to verticall align Your text without using padding and this is another question (just search for it in stackoverflow or goole).

Comment: This worked for me.. as for IE.. I don't know. IE9 doesn't recognize jQuery I guess

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
 $("#wait").height(0).animate({height: $(window).height() / 2});
```

Comment: No, sorry. It's not a stretch... more of an easing to middle of the page. Or anywhere near the top.

Comment: OK, so I'm not sure I understood what exactly you want. can u explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(function() {

$(".act").click(function() {

var h = $("#wait").height()/2;
var t = $(window).height()/2;
var pos = t - h - 50;
 $("#wait").slideDown("slow").css('top', pos);

});
});
```

You'd have to add position:relative; and width: 100% to your css though.

Comment: Sort of! I mean you got it at the right place but... it needs to start offscreen from the top and stop anywhere near the middle. like.. easing to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This will show the div and push it down the page by extending the top margin 200px. It uses [Jquery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), which lets you change a numeric property over time (read: move stuff). SlideDown is basically shorthand for calling an animate function that increases the height of an element to move it down the page. Instead of increasing the height, this keeps the same height and just moves the element to a lower part of the page.

Is this anything close to what you wanted? :D

```
$(function() {

$(".act").live("click",function() {
     $("#wait").show().animate({ marginTop: "+=200"  }, 600);
    });
});
```